# Issue with media-query

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am learning *HTML* and *CSS*. I made one site and I need to put a *media-query* on one thing but it's not working:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
  #boxmb {
    position: fixed;
    left: 60%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    z-index: 999;
  }
}
```

```html
<a class="boxmb" href="#section2"><img class="boxmb" id="boxmb" id="togglee" style="position: fixed; left: 90%; padding-top: 10%" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" id="image1" onclick="showButton();diffImage(this);showSurpriseImage();PlaySound();" ></a>
```

Here is my site: http://rickandmorty.8u.cz/index.html

Answer (score 2):

It's not working because of the *inline styling* you have inside the `img` *element* which is overriding all of your *internal / external styling* you have defined for the same *element*. *Inline styles* have the highest priority, then *internal* and *external* the least. So, in order to solve the problem, just move your *inline styles* above `@media`:

```css
#boxmb {
  position: fixed;
  left: 90%;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
 #boxmb {
   position: fixed;
   left: 60%;
   padding-top: 1%;
   z-index: 999;
 }
}
```

```html
<a class="boxmb" href="#section2">
  <img class="boxmb" id="boxmb" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="" onclick="showButton();diffImage(this);showSurpriseImage();PlaySound();">
</a>
```